# Sonarqube JIRA plugin: Linking issues to JIRA as the user logged in?

Tags: sonarqube, jira, jira-plugin

This is regarding Sonarqube 5.1.1 and JIRA 6

I'm working with Sonarqube's JIRA plugin for linking issues from Sonar to JIRA, and I was wondering if it would be possible to not only link issues to JIRA as the predefined JIRA user for Sonar, but if it would be possible to create the issues in JIRA (from Sonar still) as the user that is logged in and clicking the "link to JIRA" button on the issue.

My issue with how it's currently set up is that the reporter will then always be this predefined JIRA user for Sonar, and quite frankly it'd be much more useful if we also knew who was the one actually reporting the issues.

TL;DR I'm wondering if instead of a centralized, predefined JIRA user for Sonar, I can get each Sonar-User to also be able to report the issues.

Comment: Having the same problem here: We are authenticating to SonarQube via LDAP and would like to use the same user to create the JIRA issues instead of having one fixed SonarQube JIRA user for that.